# PHP mail() Function works with outlook and Yahoo but not Gmail

Tags: php

I have a registration form and upon completion it sends an email validation. Problem is that it works for Outlook and for Yahoo, but it is not working for Gmail. I have been tweaking headers trying to resolve the issue. I have even found another post here that is exactly my problem [PHP mail() works for Yahoo but not for Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197028/php-mail-works-for-yahoo-but-not-for-gmail)
I tried what they said in the answers and my mail still will not send to Gmail. I was going to post a comment in that question but it was 6 years old. Here are two of the methods I'm using. One is the default headers and one is to send them mail:

```
    public function sendActivationEmail() : bool {
    return mail($this->to,$this->subject,$this->getMessage(),$this->getHeaders());
}

protected function getDefaultHeaders() : string {
    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: info@abc.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: info@abc.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Cc: Client Tracker New User <farrier.clienttracker@gmail.com>\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "X-Sender: Client Tracker <farrier.clienttracker@gmail.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()."\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; // Urgent message!
    $headers .= "Return-Path: farrier.clienttracker@gmail.com\r\n"; // Return path for errors
    
    return $headers;
}
```

I'm at my wits end with this. I am not going to get a dedicated mail server and I do not know how to do any of the SMTP stuff. I did contact my hosting server and they made some changes to the SPF but that only made it so the mail went to yahoo and outlook, but not gmail.

Comment: You shouldn't put real email addresses in your posted code.

Comment: Gmail probably thinks your mail looks like spam.

Comment: There's no easy solution to this, because if there were the spammers would use it.

Comment: those are testing emails and there is nothing in the spam... I'm not a dimwit

Comment: We can't help you with a misconfigured outbound email system. Gmail does not take kindly to incoming email from random SMTP hosts or even small-ish webhosts - I might suggest you use a "trusted" email gateway provider such as SendGrid - or send emails to Gmail directly by despositing them using IMAP.

Comment: @Cavalier "those are testing emails and there is nothing in the spam" - Gmail has no way of knowing if your emails are spam or not, but it errs on the side of caution by blocking emails from unknown/untrusted/low-volume SMTP gateways because those are the main source of spam today. Unfortunately the "best" approach overall seems to simply to be to _pay for SMTP_ with a known-good provider rather than going with self-hosted options.

Comment: @Dai they are real gmail accounts, but I do not use them for my actual business. They are to try to figure out why gmail is not taking the email. It has me buffaloed

Comment: My host has been around for nearly 20 years. It is phpwebhosting.com, I have no clue how their SMTP is set up though or how their mail service works :( But I have been with them for a very long time.

Comment: I do have another option. Rather than using the email, I could use the SMS and send a message to their phone for verification. :( But then I would not be notified of a new user that has registered with the site

Comment: @Dai "or send emails to Gmail directly by despositing them using IMAP" How does the IMAP work? is there any good docuementation? Can I code it with PHP?

Comment: "made some changes to the SPF " -- Have you set up SPF and DKIM validation for your server domain AND checked in Outlook and Yahoo that it passed validation?  If not, GMail is not likely to accept what could be spoofed mail lying about the sender.

Comment: @DaveS My hosting provider said they made changes to the SPF: Here is his comment:  "Hi,

You may need to modify the headers of your emails, but I also made an adjustment to your SPF record which may help. I would test with the new SPF records first, before you modify the headers.

Best regards,"
I do not know what he did though as I do not have access to the hosting server.

Comment: @DaveS How do I check in outlook and yahoo to see if they passed validation? The emails were in the inboxes. Not the spam...

Comment: If you view the headers in Outlook for the incoming mail it should show whether SPF and DKIM were present and whether they passed.  You need to double-click to open the mail in its own window, go to File then Properties to see the headers  (That's desktop outlook, phone or web steps will be different but a Google search will find them for you)

Comment: @Daves It does not show a File tab on the page :(

Comment: Do a Google search for your version of Outlook and how to view full headers.

Comment: https://www.mail-tester.com is also often very helpful in figuring out what issues there might be with the whole setup, regarding SPF / DKIM, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from [Google Help Center](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en&ref_topic=10685331&sjid=18043118995921426328-EU):

> Starting November 2022, new senders who send email to personal Gmail
> accounts *must set up either SPF or DKIM*. Google performs random
> checks on new sender messages to personal Gmail accounts to verify
> they’re authenticated. Messages without at least one of these
> authentication methods will be rejected or marked as spam. This
> requirement doesn’t apply to you if you’re an existing sender.
> However, we recommend you always set up SPF and DKIM to protect your
> organization’s email and to support future authentication
> requirements.

So it is necessary to set up at least one of SPF or DKIM. SPF can set up by adding a TXT record in the DNS as explained in [Define your SPF record](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10685031?hl=en). DKIM, however, needs to be set up in your mail server, so if you have a mail provider that does not yet support DKIM, SPF is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on my hosting server. They had to identify that my domain and ip was permited. Now in the header information of the emails the SPF=Pass and the DKIM=Pass. So now all the emails are going through.

Comment: Share a few details about the solution to make the answer more helpful for others.

Comment: @not2savvy I'm not completely sure what they did. They made the changes on the hosting server. Before the changes, the mail that did go through, the headers for the SPF was a soft fail, the DKIM was a fail. So unfortunately I do not know what they did on their end. :(

Comment: In the meantime, I've encountered the same problems when sending emails to GMail recipients. It seems Google has made a change to be restrictive in that it requires at least one of a successful SPF or DKIM check for any incoming emails. It does not seem to affect all GMail accounts yet, but I would expect that it eventually will.